# Function only calls the same block with different input

Tags: java, function, int, double, overloading

```
import java.io.*;
public class LargestOfTwo{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
        BufferedReader scan = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        double num1, num2 , large;

        System.out.println("Enter two numbers, and I will show you which one's largest!\n");
        System.out.println("Enter two numbers: ");
        num1 = Double.parseDouble(scan.readLine());
        num2 = Double.parseDouble(scan.readLine());

        large = largest(num1,num2);
        System.out.print("Largest of the numbers is "+large);
    }


    private static double largest(int x,double y){
        System.out.println("id");
        if (x>y)
            return x;
        else 
            return y;
    }

    private static double largest(double x,int y){
        System.out.println("ii");
        if (x>y)
            return x;
        else 
            return y;
    }
    private static double largest(double x,double y){ 
        System.out.println("dd");
        if (x>y)
            return x;
        else 
            return y;
    }
}
```

I need to find the largest of 2 inputted numbers, using function overloading(input float values and int values) .

I checked if the call goes to the specific method, by those print texts (id, ii, dd).

```
private static double largest(int x,double y){
        System.out.println("id");
}


private static double largest(double x,int y){
        System.out.println("ii");
}



private static double largest(double x,double y){ 
        System.out.println("dd");
}
```

But it executes the dd only :-

`private static double largest(double x,double y)`

is it because the wrong variable initialization or not? and how can I fix this ?

Comment: since you initialize reference "double num1, num2;" as double type you just send copy of 2 double reference bit pattern in this case jvm thinks dd is the best fit

Comment: any fix for this ?

Comment: why you care? Lets say I enter 3 which perfectly fits integer as well as double range, so you can choose which is best fit for you, if you want to handle decimal places also I would just go with double also it has bigger range, if I understand right they dont ask you to detect which primitive type

Answer (score 2):

Both `num1` and `num2` are declared as `double`, so there is really no other outcome to expect other than what you got.

Comment: So how can I fix that ?
I need answer for this question "find the largest of 2 inputted numbers, using function overloading(input float values and int values) ."

Comment: Instructions are unclear. What exactly do they expect you to do? It seems like overloading is unnecessary.

Comment: Find the largest among the two inputted numbers, using function overloading concept(input float values and int values)   :- this is the exact question my university made for assignments. :V

Comment: @JoeTinnySpace then take a look at Nkem Cels answer. Also notice that you're saying you need to compare float and int so consider defining the variables as float (therefor parse the Scanner input to float to) istead of double.

Answer (score 2):

In this line, num1 and num2 is double. So the method which has double parameters is calling.

```
 num1 = Double.parseDouble(scan.readLine());
 num2 = Double.parseDouble(scan.readLine());
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to call the `largest(int x,double y)` method, then cast `num1` as an integer, i.e. `largest((int)num1, num2).` if you want to call `largest(int x,int y)` then cast both `num1` and `num2` as integers